# Populate a column in Kendo Grid based on separate Datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid like what I've posted below. I'm populating the grid based on the data in the url I provided for it. However, there is one column on the grid, the `flag` column, which I would like to be a separate datasource to populate that column, based on the id. The datasource for that column would look something like:

```
[{id:1234, flag: 'N'}, {id:5678, flag:'Y'}]
```

Is there a way where I can populate just 1 column in the grid based on a completely different datasource from the rest of the grid? The flag would need to be placed on the row of its corresponding id. If so, how can I implement this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: url
                    },
                    pageSize: 30
                },
                height: 400,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                    field: "id",
                    title: "ID",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name"
                }, {
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "LastName"
                }, {
                    field: "flag",
                    title: "Flag",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a foreign key column.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!